# Metadata "keywords" or "descriptions" for non-controlled-vocabulary search terms?

Tags: metadata, file-management, tagging, keywords

I have a bunch of unorganized scanned family photos. I want to add metadata to make them more searchable.

I thought I'd mostly use the IPTC `keyword` field (because I don't have a need for well-written sentences like I think the `description` field is meant for), but I do want to include pretty specific terms — sometimes relevant only to single photos — so I can later search for and find certain photos quickly. On the other hand, I'd like to develop a controlled vocabulary of keywords for recurring subjects. So, is it good practice to put both controlled vocabulary terms AND more specific one-off terms in the `keywords` field?

Alternatively, is it bad practice to "keyword stuff" the `description` field with non-sentence terms to aid search-ability (while keeping the `keywords` field limited to the controlled vocabulary)? This approach seems like it would be better for navigating using a keyword list that many programs offer, since you wouldn't have thousands of keywords, while still allowing you to find photos by searching for more specific terms you included in the `description` field.

It feels like there should be a metadata field "in between" `keywords` and `descriptions`; i.e., a "search terms" field that wouldn't show up in keyword lists to browse by, but also wouldn't junk up a nicely written description.

I know people say "it's up to you" to choose how to use these fields... But I'm curious what others do, and what you find to be the pros & cons of different approaches.